# Is an encrypted SSIS package with password fully encrypted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

If you natively encrypt an SSIS package using Encrypt all with password (EncryptAllWithPassword), identified from MS as: "Uses a password to encrypt the whole package. The package is encrypted by using a password that the user supplies when the package is created or exported. To open the package in SSIS Designer or run the package by using the dtexec command prompt utility, the user must provide the package password. Without the password the user cannot access or run the package." Does this mean that all data WITHIN the package is also encrypted? Or just the surrounding package and how it is trasmitted?

The reason I am asking is, I am relatively new to SSIS and my client is being extremely careful with how their data is sent over the internet. If I create an SSIS package and set the protection level to Encrypt All With Password, can I safely say that everything in that package is secure until it's run with the proper password? Or do I need to take a different approach.

Comment: There is no data within a package. Not sure what you mean, do you mean that the resulting file from an export is encrypted?

Comment: Yeah sorry... I was typing quicker than my brain was thinking. Basically the client wants an SSIS package which will grab a batch of data from their instance of SQLServer 2k8 and send it to our instance. On our instance we'll process it. The data is sensitive and I've already read about how to encrypt specific sensitive columns within the data being sent, but i'm curious about using the "Encrypt all". Does that truly encrypt everything the package deals with? All data?

Comment: @optionsix - No it just encrypts the package, not the data the package processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypt all data with password - uses an arbitrary password provided by the package designer to encrypt entire package content, applying Triple DES cipher algorithm. The password is required in order to open, import, export, or execute the package. Since its content is obfuscated, attempting to view it directly does not provide any meaningful insight into its structure.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3898676/Securing-the-Content-of-SSIS-Packages.htm

Comment: According to this, looks like it encrypts the whole shebang.

Comment: Beware - the term "data" in that article doesn't sound like the same "data" you're referring to in your comment on the original question.  The article means "data" like connection strings, package variables, passwords, etc.  It is not providing transport encryption for your data connections.

Answer (score 0):

Encryption levels are described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx).
Encrypting all with password protects both connection strings, passwords, and database schema (all the package is encrypted), so it's save to use this option with sensitive data.

Encrypting with user key might be slightly better as keys are generally longer than passwords, but in practice just use the method that is more convenient.